# How can I improve the following mysql selects?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-db, zend-db-select

I am currently refactoring a legacy application and converting piece by piece over to zend framework 1.12.

I am scratching my head as to how to convert this over to zend db, is there a way that this can be done in one query?

Right now I see that it fetches a list of folders first and then runs an additional query per folder... 
Running this as one query will improve performance, right?

```
$folders_query = DB::Query("select * from contacts_folders order by sort_order, name");
while($folders = DB::FetchArray($folders_query)){
    $counts_total = DB::QueryOne("SELECT count(cm.messages_id) AS total
    FROM contacts_basics cb, contacts_messages cm
    WHERE cb.contacts_id = cm.contacts_id
    AND cm.folders_id =  '" . $folders['folders_id'] . "'
    AND cm.status = '1'
    AND cm.mark =  '0'");


    if ($counts_total >0){ 
        $folders_name = '<strong>' . $folders['name'] . ' (' . $counts_total . ')</strong>'; 
    } else { 
        $folders_name = $folders['name']; 
    }

    echo '<li><a href="messages.php?fID=' . $folders['folders_id'] . '">';

    echo $folders_name;

    echo '</a></li>';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do both in the same query

```
SELECT cf.*, count(cm.messages_id) AS total
FROM contacts_folders cf left outer join
     contacts_messages cm
     on cf.id = cm.folders_id and
        cm.status = '1' AND cm.mark =  '0' left outer join
     contacts_basics cb
     on cb.contacts_id = cm.contacts_id
group by cf.folders_id
order by cf.sort_order, cf.name;
```

This uses a `left outer join` to be sure that you get all folders, even if there are no messages (which is how the original code works).  Because of the `left outer join`, the conditions need to be moved into `on` clauses.

It also fetches all the information from the folders as well as the total.  If there are no messages, then it should return 0 for that folder.

Answer (score 0):

There was a minor bug in Gordon's answer but I figured it out thanks to him.

I changed

```
contacts_basics cb left outer join
```

To:

```
left outer join contacts_basics cb
```

The following code works as expected:

```
public function getMenuCounts(){
    $raw = "SELECT cf.*, count(cm.messages_id) AS total
    FROM contacts_folders cf left outer join
    contacts_messages cm
    on cf.folders_id = cm.folders_id and
    cm.status = '1' AND cm.mark =  '0'
    left outer join contacts_basics cb
    on cb.contacts_id = cm.contacts_id
    group by cf.folders_id
    order by cf.sort_order, cf.name;";
    $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
    $stmt = $db->query($raw);
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

Comment: . . Amusing.  That was because I originally wrote the joins in the order you have in the original query.  Then I realized that the table that with the right field for the join was `cm`, not `cb`.  One solution would have been `right outer join`, but I much prefer `left outer join` (habits), and I guess I didn't fully fix the syntax.